Python won't find the ENV in my docker container

I've a problem with my docker container. I want to set a ENV variable through the `docker run` command using the `--env ENV=VALUE` parameter. If I lookup the ENV in my docker entrypoint script using the bash command `env`, my ENV variables are shown like i've set them in the `docker run`. But when I do `os.environ` or `os.system("env")` inside of the container, the ENV variables are not showing. The ENV I've set in my Dockerfile is listed via the bash command and in python.
I'm using the python:3.12-alpine3.20 docker image. My Dockerfile:
# This is the stage for the final image
FROM python:3.12-alpine3.20

WORKDIR /src
COPY ./python/src/ .
COPY ./python/docker_entrypoint.sh /

RUN apk add --no-cache sudo bluez tzdata
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin

ENTRYPOINT sh /docker_entrypoint.sh

docker_enrtypoint.sh:
#!/bin/sh

python3.12 api_endpoints.py &
sudo python3.12 main.py

I start the container with:
docker run --name=MY_CONTAINER --restart=on-failure --env LOOP=10 IMAGE:TAG

ENV listing using env bash command in my docker_entrypoint.sh inside of the container:
HOSTNAME=H-Desktop
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=24.0
SHLVL=2
HOME=/root
LOOP=10
GPG_KEY=7169605F62C751356D054A26A821E680E5FA6305
PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/dbf0c85f76fb6e1ab42aa672ffca6f0a675d9ee4/public/get-pip.py
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LANG=C.UTF-8
PYTHON_VERSION=3.12.3
PWD=/src
PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=dfe9fd5c28dc98b5ac17979a953ea550cec37ae1b47a5116007395bfacff2ab9
TZ=Europe/Berlin

ENV listing using os.system("env") in my main.py inside of the container:
SUDO_GID=0
MAIL=/var/mail/root
USER=root
HOSTNAME=H-Desktop
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
SUDO_UID=0
LOGNAME=root
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LANG=C.UTF-8
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/python3.12 main.py
SHELL=/bin/sh
SUDO_USER=root
PWD=/src
TZ=Europe/Berlin

ENV listing using print(os.environ) in my main.py inside of the container:
{
  "HOSTNAME": "H-Desktop",
  "TERM": "xterm",
  "PATH": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
  "LANG": "C.UTF-8",
  "TZ": "Europe/Berlin",
  "MAIL": "/var/mail/root",
  "LOGNAME": "root",
  "USER": "root",
  "HOME": "/root",
  "SHELL": "/bin/sh",
  "SUDO_COMMAND": "/usr/local/bin/python3.12 main.py",
  "SUDO_USER": "root",
  "SUDO_UID": "0",
  "SUDO_GID": "0"
}

The TZ variable for the timezone, which was set in my Dockerfile is (like expected) showing up inside the container for python but the LOOP variable isn't there... somehow. I don't know why that's a bit of strange behaviour since it's showing up when I do the env via bash directly.
Would be great if someone has an idea, what's going on here. I'll do a quick and dirty workaround until I know more about this.
My Workaround: 
I do env > .env in my docker_entrypoint.sh since there're all ENV variables showing and then I load the ENVs into the python os.environ via the load_env function which gets imported into my main.py. Since I only want to use this when it's running in the container, it's looking for the file called DOCKER, which I've created in the Dockerfile. I don't like it at all but it works...
import os


def load_env():
  print(os.listdir('.'))
  if 'DOCKER' in os.listdir('.'):
    with open(file='.env', mode='r') as file: ENV = file.readlines()
    for env in ENV:
      env = env.strip()
      key, value = env.split('=')
      os.environ[key] = value

Solution 
I removed the sudo call in my docker_entrypoint.sh. Seems like the ENV will be swapped out when sudo gets called. Also sorry for this kinda weird post... Thanks to all who were trying to help me :D
How can I access the ENV variables using python inside of my docker container?

I have checked with simple python code to access the LOOP variable and it works in my case. Are you referencing this environment variable anywhere else in your code?

No. I only check the value of the ENV on top of my main.py file. Which docker image did you used? Maybe it's an alpine issue... I used the alpine image for reducing my image size from 1GiB to around 100MiB....

This isn’t a [mre]. Please remove as many irrelevant parts (stages, layers, dependencies, capabilities, volumes) as you can while preserving the problem – you may even solve it by doing this – and include all the remaining parts in full, like the (similarly minimized) contents of docker_entrypoint.sh.

I know it's isn't minimal reproducible example since I'm not sure if it's a docker or a python problem.  I tried to only mention the important things. Thanks for your comment, I'll take care about that more :D

As @Hans pointed out sudo is not required in the docker since you aren't changing the user. It will by default run with EUID 0.

@tbhaxor This solved my problem. I didn't knew about this.

sudo doesn't preserve environment variables. Since you're already running as root in the container, there's no need to run sudo. So try removing it in your script like this
#!/bin/sh

python3.12 api_endpoints.py &
python3.12 main.py

Or, if you need to still use sudo, you can use the -E option on it to preserve environment variables.
#!/bin/sh

python3.12 api_endpoints.py &
sudo -E python3.12 main.py


Thanks, this solved it. I didn't knew that before... so when I exec something as sudo, I'll also have the sudo env? Or why does this ENV behaviour happen?
